# php switch statement with wildcard in the string

Tags: php, string, switch-statement, case, wildcard

I would like to have a **switch statement** with both literal cases and cases with a **wildcard** in the string:

```
switch($category){
    case 'A**': $artist= 'Pink Floyd'; break;
    case 'B**': $artist= 'Lou Reed'; break;
    case 'C01': $artist= 'David Bowie'; break;
    case 'C02': $artist= 'Radiohead'; break;
    case 'C03': $artist= 'Black Angels'; break;
    case 'C04': $artist= 'Glenn Fiddich'; break;
    case 'C05': $artist= 'Nicolas Jaar'; break;
    case 'D**': $artist= 'Flat Earth Society'; break;
}
```

Of course the * will be taken literally here cause I define it as a string, so this does not work, but you know what I would like to accomplish: for the A, B and D cases the numbers can be whatever (*). Maybe with preg_match this is possible but that really blows my head. I Googled, I really did.

Comment: Use if() {} else if () ... {} else {} with substr

Comment: You can't do that with a switch. Use an associative array with a regex as a key, and the value as the result, then pass the whole thing in a foreach() with preg_match().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with switch, of course only, if it really best approach. Very long switch list of cases is a headache...

```
switch($category){
    case 'C01': $artist = 'David Bowie';    break;
    case 'C02': $artist = 'Radiohead';      break;
    case 'C03': $artist = 'Black Angels';   break;
    case 'C04': $artist = 'Glenn Fiddich';  break;
    case 'C05': $artist = 'Nicolas Jaar';   break;
    default:
        switch(substr($category,0,1)){
            case A: $artist = 'Pink Floyd';         break;
            case B: $artist = 'Lou Reed';           break;
            case D: $artist = 'Flat Earth Society'; break;
            default:    echo'somethig is wrong with category!';}}
```

Comment: this was exactly where I was looking for! No need for preg_match makes me happy. Thanks so much for this simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$rules = [
    '#A(.{2,2})#' => 'Pink Floyd',
    '#B(.{2,2})#' => 'Lou Reed',
    'C01' => 'David Bowie',
    'C02' => 'Radiohead',
    'C03' => 'Black Angels',
    'C04' => 'Glenn Fiddich',
    'C05' => 'Nicolas Jaar',
    '#D(.{2,2})#' => 'Flat Earth Society'
];

$category = 'Dxx';
$out = '';

foreach ( $rules as $key => $value )
{
    /* special case */
    if ( $key[0] === '#' )
    {
        if ( !preg_match($key, $category) )
            continue;

        $out = $value;
        break;
    }
    
    /* Simple key */
    if ( $key === $category )
    {
        $out = $value;
        break;
    }
}

echo $out."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

i write a function. this is with `preg_match` but it is short and reusable.

```
function preg_switch(string $str, array $rules) {
    foreach($rules as $key => $value) {
        if(preg_match("/(^$key$)/", $str) > 0)
            return $value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
$artist = preg_switch("Bdd", [
    "A.." => "Pink Floyd",
    "B.." => "Lou Reed",
    "C01" => "David Bowie",
    "C02" => "Radiohead",
    "C03" => "Black Angels",
    "C04" => "Glenn Fiddich",
    "C05" => "Nicolas Jaar",
    "D.." => "Flat Earth Society",
]);
```

instead of `*` you have to use `.`

Comment: You run preg_match for every keys and you rely on incomplete regex

Comment: yeh. string comparison is faster but i don't think there is so much difference in this case. if number of all letters is small like less than 80 characters and do it for 1000000 times. time difference will be less than 1 second.

Comment: what do you mean of incomplete regex. do you mean it's not gonna work in some case?

Comment: I mean in your array keys, you only have one part of the final regex, this can lead to bugs. And the key by itself don't let you know it can be used as a regex.